# Stop cursor movement when using up and down arrow

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a live search input that shows results and lets you use the up and down arrows when the results popup but I want to prevent the cursor from moving left or right when using the up and down arrows. I cannot figure this out. I tried `e.preventDefault()` with no luck. Here is what I have tried:

```
    if(e.which == 40){

        e.preventDefault();

        current = results.find('li.hover');
        current.removeClass();
        var next = current.next('li');

        if(next.length == 0){
            next = current.parent().parent().parent().next().find('li:first');

            /* Go back to the top */
            if(next.length == 0){
                next = results.find('li:first');
            }
        }

        next.addClass('hover');
        return false;
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: As an aside, try using `.closest()` ([ref](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)) instead of multiple `.parent()` functions - just to keep things more readable ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Are you binding this onkeyup or keydown? If you are using keydown, you can prevent it, if your using keyup, the event already happened. Otherwise e.preventDefault() should be working.

Comment: I am using `live('keyup')` when I had it set to keydown it wouldn't allow any input in my field at all. I didn't even have any preventDefaults.

Comment: Strange, then you probaby return false at the end of the function or use a e.preventDefault() on another spot.

Comment: I had to split up my search and put it in the keyup and have the arrow work in the keydown. But this answer helped!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like...

```
$('#content').on('keydown', function(event) {
    var key = event.originalEvent.key;
    if (key == 'ArrowDown' || key == 'ArrowUp') {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});

$('#content').on('keyup', function(event) {
    // do stuff
});
```